# java кидает эксепшены при запуске elasticsearch

Tags: исключения, elasticsearch, openjdk

ос centos 7 при запуске эластика выдает такие эксепшены, что делать?

```
 /opt/elasticsearch-6.2.3/bin/elasticsearch
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/elasticsearch-6.2.3/config/jvm.options
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:58)
```

Comment: От имени какого юзера запускается эластик? Какие права на файле jvm.options?

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась добавлением репозитория и утсоновкой эластика через yum
ссылку на доку оставлю на всякий 
[Install elasticsearch with RPM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/rpm.html#rpm-repo)